# Checking if coredumps are disabled for current process

Tags: linux

Is there an easy way to check whether the current process has coredumps enabled, so a library can instead return an error before loading encryption keys?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ulimit command/system call to check the core dump size. If it is zero, no core dumps. Please note that the manual page suggest using getrlimit() and setrlimit() instead of ulimit()

Comment: To be extra sure, check the hard limit, not the soft, and also check whether a process can increase its limit (has `CAP_SYS_RESOURCE` capability).

Comment: @Roman, thanks for pointing out the capability part. I totally missed it.